# What is the use of the first parameter in HTML.DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm reading the documentation on HTML.DropDownListFor and it states the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList
)
```

What does the expression do? I've been reading and it says to bind it to a property?

I've used the following code:

```
 @(Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SiteList[0], new SelectList(Model.SiteList, "LocationID", "Description",Model.SiteList[5].LocationID)))
```

and that code works just as fine as:

```
 @(Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SiteList[0].LocationID, new SelectList(Model.SiteList, "LocationID", "Description",Model.SiteList[5].LocationID)))
```

and

```
@(Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SiteList[0].Description, new SelectList(Model.SiteList, "LocationID", "Description",Model.SiteList[5].LocationID)))
```

where SiteList is a:

```
List<Site>
```

with Site being:

```
public class Site {
    public string LocationID;
    public string Description;
}
```

I don't understand what the purpose of the lambda is in the example and how it's being used in the output?

Comment: When you select an information on dropdown, that information on `POST` will be binded to a property of the Model. But in your code, you interfer with the list that populate the dropdown and bind your selected value in the same list, this confuses you.

Comment: With that property name it will not only assign the `id` & `name` attributes of rendered `Select` HTML, but it will also autoselect the dropdown with that property value.

Comment: You need to show the model your using in the view. `@Html.DropDownList()` binds to a property in your model! So if you have a property named (say) `int SelectedLocation` then `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation, new SelectList(Model.SiteList, "LocationID", "Description"))` would display the collection of sites and bind the selected one to the property `SelectedLocation`

Comment: And using `x => x.SiteList[0].LocationID` makes no sense. Your trying to bind the first item in the collection to itself.

Answer (score 1):

So you would normally have a separate property on your model for this next to your list. When you select a value from the list it sets the property that this is bound to.

```
class ListType{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}    

class ViewModel{
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List { get; set; } //This is generated from a list of ListType objects
     public string Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Selected, Model.List)
```

This means when the form is posted back then the Selected property has the value of your selected item in the list.

Comment: Is there a way to choose the name of the property? (@Html.DropDownListFor(x => "PropertyName.MyName.Selected", Model.list)?

Answer (score 0):

See the html generated by the three expression. The name and id would be different in all the cases. These name is used while binding the selected value to the property of the model.The name of the element should be same as the name of the property to which the selected value is to be bidden upon posting of the page.The  expression gives a friendly way to give name to the element to achieve the purpose.